Motorized damper
It seems I have a motorized damper attached to my duct work of my HVAC system. It was unplugged when I went into the attic to change my filter. When I initially moved in I had an HVAC company come out to look at my system because some rooms were not cooling. Could this have been unplugged by the tech to have better air flow?  He did open some dampers manually. I plugged it back in, will this cause my electric bill to increase as well?

yes, it could have been ... if the damper uses electricity, then yes, there will be an increase in usage ... you're not asking questions that have useful answers

If working well, maybe under a dollar for the year on the bill.  Having the system tuned to your comfort level, not cooling unused rooms, will matter more to your bill.

There is zero chance you will notice a change in your electric bill due to a damper.  There is a much higher chance that the damper was the cause of rooms not cooling.
